# Joint convexity of quadratic form x'Ax

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I know that $g(x,A) = x^{t}A^{-1}x$ is jointly convex in $(x,A)$ for $x \in R^{n}$ and $A \in S^{n}_{++}$and was wondering if  $f(x,A) = x^{t}Ax$ is also jointly convex in (x,A) for $x \in R^{n}$ and $A \in S^{n}_{++}$.

It is abvious that $f$ is element-wise convex in $x$ and $A$ but I was unable to show the joint convexity. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case $n=1$ this reduces to the question, whether 
$$
f(x,y) = x^2y 
$$
is convex on $\mathbb R\times(0,\infty)$. The second derivative is given by
$$
\nabla^2f(x,y)=2\pmatrix{y & x\\x&0},
$$
which is positive semidefinite if and only if $x=0$. Hence $f$ cannot be convex on its domain.